# How do I extract a table using table id using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning how to scrape tables from https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2018_gbg.html using BeautifulSoup.

This particular page has multiple tables, and I want to be able to extract a particular table based on table id. When inspecting the code, I can see each table does have a unique id.

I have tried the following, which returns an empty list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2018_gbg.html"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table=soup.find_all('table', id='sortableTable0')
print(table)
```

I can extract all tables if I search by table class which is in the same tag, so I am unsure why searching for a particular table id isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That table is being dynamically generated through JavaScript, so you would need to use something that can handle that. One option in Python is to use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) as shown below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/teams/adelaide/2018_gbg.html")

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

table = soup.find_all('table', {'id':'sortableTable0'})
print(table)
```

Interestingly the page source has the following element before the `div` containing the table:

`<noscript>This page requires Javascript enabled to function<br><br></noscript>`